# Python: variable returns to the initial valor after loop changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, tkinter, infinite-loop

im trying to do a simple program in Python to send a message when my web valor changes (just context), the question is im doing a loop with tkinter to show a window, i have declared a function that is called in my tkinter loop, i have global variables, but when i change an global variable into the loop, at the next round the variable returns to the initial valor, here is my code:

```
#just variables (i have simplified the code)
aux1 = False
aux2 = False
aux3 = False
def search(url, aux):
    try:
        host_get = request.get(ip)
        if host_get.status_code == 200:
        host_cont = host.get.text
        host_soup = BeautifulSoup(host_cont, 'lxml')
        try:
            host_stat = host_soup.find('div', class='UP'.getText())
            aux = False
        except:
            if aux == False:
                MessageBox.showWarning("Alert", "Host is DOWN")
                aux = True
                #The problem is here
                #After doing this (aux = True), the program still doing (aux = False) options
            elif aux == True:
                print("Host still DOWN")
            else:
                MessageBox.showWarning("Alert", "Host is DOWN")
                aux = True
def search_loop:
    #i have many websites, but i showed only 1 for the example code
    url1 = "website1.com"
    global aux1
    search(url1, aux1)
    #5 seconds to do the next loop
    time.sleep(5)

class WindowClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window1 = tk.Tk()
        self.button1()
        self.window1.mainloop()
    def button1(self):
        self.startbutton = tk.Button(self.window1, command=self.startloop, text='Start')
        self.startbutton.place(x=50, y=50)
    def startloop(self):
        search_loop()
app1 = WindowClass()
```

yep, its a infinite loop, the problem i have is on the loop i think, but idk, i have tried many things to do it correctly but i cant, so arrived here, hope someone can help me,
sorry for the broken english, idk if i explained correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't pass global variables around as parameters. You are passing a copy of the global variable into your search function, which is why the modification is lost.

Try changing you code so that you use the globals directly:

```
aux1 = False
aux2 = False
aux3 = False

def search():
    global aux1, aux2, aux3
    
    aux1 = True
    
      
class main():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        search()
        
        print(aux1)
        print(aux2)
        print(aux3) 
        
        # result
        # True
        # False
        # False
       
main()
```

Comment: Tysm! It worked, i did knew i can't pass global variables as a parameter